# Is a continuous function in two variables necessarily equicontinuous in one variable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $K \in \mathcal{C}\left(\left[0, 1\right]\times\left[0, 1\right]\right)$. Then, is it necessarily the case that the set of functions $\left\{g_y(x):g_y(x) = K(x,y), \forall y \in [0,1]\right\}$ is equicontinuous?

Seems silly, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$[0,1]^2$ is compact, hence $K$ is uniformly continuous, i.e. for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta$ such that if $\|(x,y)-(x',y')\|<\delta$, then $|K(x,y)-K(x',y')|<\varepsilon$. Since $|x-x'|<\delta$ implies that $\|(x,y)-(x',y)\|<\delta$, you immediately get the equicontinuity of your family.

Comment: Thank you! So I was right all along, I forgot that I could immediately show that $K$ is uniformly continuous. That could have helped me to prove the result!

Thanks for the hint.